# What ancient manuscripts were lost when the Huguenots destroyed the Cluny Abbey library?

Tags: france, catholic-church, classical-antiquity, early-modern

I've heard that the destruction of the great [Cluny Abbey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluny_Abbey) library (in the Burgundy region of France) both by the Huguenots (1562) and later during the French Revolution meant that a massive number of extremely important manuscripts were lost. I've read that the magnitude of this destruction in terms of lost knowledge was second only to the sacking of the great library of Alexandria. But it's hard to find an actual list of manuscripts purported to have been destroyed at Cluny.

Comment: Hello! This looks like an interesting question. However, what's your source for the claim that the lost knowledge is second only to the destruction of the Library in Alexandria (which, by the way, had nothing to do with Muslims)? Also, your Wikipedia link doesn't even mention this 1562 destruction by the Huguenots.

Comment: @gktscrk The section "Library" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluny_Abbey#Library in the cited page talks about 1562 destruction by Hugenots.